# SQL query with multi select options using AND operator

Tags: sql

I want to write an SQL query for filtering the data. I have two drop down menus from which a user can select two options and when you hit the search button the query brings back the records from database. I used simple "AND" operator and it works fine when values from both drop down menus are selected. But the problem happens when one drop down value is selected and second value is left empty or not selected and when you try to search the records then because of "Null" value the AND operator do not shows you record from the database. I don't want to use OR operator because the conditional part of query should work when both conditions are true.

```
SELECT * FROM `contacts` WHERE `option_1` = 'buyer' AND `option_2` = ''
```

Answer (score 0):

The typical pattern you would follow here is:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM contacts
WHERE (option_1 = ? OR ? IS NULL) AND
      (option_2 = ? OR ? IS NULL);
```

To the four `?` above you would bind the `option_1` dropdown value for the first two `?`, and the `option_2` dropdown value for the second two `?`.

If your setup really be such that for non selected options you would pass empty string to the database, then use this version:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM contacts
WHERE (option_1 = ? OR ? = '') AND
      (option_2 = ? OR ? = '');
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear whether you want data to be fetched if either or both of the options are not selected by user,

with a simple tweak you could make your query fetch records even if either or both of the options are null

eg. you could change your query something like this

SELECT * FROM 'contacts'
WHERE ISNULL('option_1','buyer') = 'buyer' AND ISNULL('option_2','') = ''

Comment: The query should work if both options are selected (which is an AND operation) and it should also work if only of the option is selected.

Comment: This query does cater to both possible combinations, please try and check whether you get desired output.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, the option_1 is matched with buyer, so in case of option_1 is not selected, what do want it to default to? as in do you want any default value to be specified in case it is NULL? if yes, what should that be? I have edited the query to default to 'buyer' in case first option is not selected/is NULL